# @Autowired is not injected in @ManagedBean, causes NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jsf, managed-bean

I'm developing a Java EE app using Spring, JSF and Hibernate, but I'm getting an error related to the use of beans.

This is the class `Commande`:

```
package dao;

Generated 6 août 2014 13:11:43 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
* Commande generated by hbm2java
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "commande", catalog = "gest")
public class Commande implements java.io.Serializable {

private long idCom;
private Categorie categorie;
private Produits produits;
private int quantite;

public Commande() {
}
public Commande(long idCom,int quantite){
this.idCom=idCom;
this.quantite=quantite;
 }
public Commande(long idCom, Categorie categorie, Produits produits,
        int quantite) {
    this.idCom = idCom;
    this.categorie = categorie;
    this.produits = produits;
    this.quantite = quantite;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "id_com", unique = true, nullable = false)
public long getIdCom() {
    return this.idCom;
}

public void setIdCom(long idCom) {
    this.idCom = idCom;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_cat", nullable = false)
public Categorie getCategorie() {
    return this.categorie;
}

public void setCategorie(Categorie categorie) {
    this.categorie = categorie;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_prod", nullable = false)
public Produits getProduits() {
    return this.produits;
}

public void setProduits(Produits produits) {
    this.produits = produits;
}

@Column(name = "quantite", nullable = false)
public int getQuantite() {
    return this.quantite;
}

public void setQuantite(int quantite) {
    this.quantite = quantite;
}
}
```

i used an interfece called Commandser

```
package service;
import java.util.List;

import dao.Commande;

public interface Commandser {
List<Commande> findall();
}
```

the implementation of commandser:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import dao.Commande;
@Service("commandeser")
public class Commimpl implements Commandser {
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactrory;
public List<Commande> findall() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sessionFactrory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Commande").list();
}
}
```

definition of the Bean:

```
package webf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import dao.Commande;

import org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlScrollableDataTable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; */
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import service.Commandser;
import service.Commimpl;
@ManagedBean(name="commandeBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CommandeBean implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private transient Commandser commandeser;
private transient HtmlScrollableDataTable commandetablt;
private List<Commande> commandeList;
@PostConstruct
public void intit(){
    commandeList=commandeser.findall();
}
public HtmlScrollableDataTable getCommandetablt() {
    return commandetablt;
}
public void setCommandetablt(HtmlScrollableDataTable commandetablt) {
    this.commandetablt = commandetablt;
}
public List<Commande> getCommandeList() {
    return commandeList;
}
public void setCommandeList(List<Commande> commandeList) {
    this.commandeList = commandeList;
}
```

faces-config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              

xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
<application>
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config> 
}
```

and i am getting this error:

```
août 06, 2014 1:01:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at webf.CommandeBean.intit(CommandeBean.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at      com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:160)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1110)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.createComponent(UIComponentTag.java:212)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:506)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:744)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspx_meth_rich_005fscrollableDataTable_005f0(CommandeList_jsp.java:219)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f0(CommandeList_jsp.java:175)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(CommandeList_jsp.java:131)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspService(CommandeList_jsp.java:93)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:108)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

août 06, 2014 1:01:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/Finale] threw exception [javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Erreur lors de l’injection de ressources dans le bean géré «commandeBean»] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at webf.CommandeBean.intit(CommandeBean.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:160)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1110)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag.createComponent(UIComponentTag.java:212)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:506)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:744)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspx_meth_rich_005fscrollableDataTable_005f0(CommandeList_jsp.java:219)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f0(CommandeList_jsp.java:175)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(CommandeList_jsp.java:131)
    at org.apache.jsp.CommandeList_jsp._jspService(CommandeList_jsp.java:93)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:108)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and finnaly the jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>List des commandes</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h:form id="mainform">
<rich:scrollableDataTable id="commandetablt" binding="#{commandeBean.commandetablt}" value="#{commandeBean.commandeList}"
var="commande" width="360px" height="200px">
<rich:column id="idCom" width="60px">
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="id"></h:outputText></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{commande.idCom}"></h:outputText>
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="quantite" width="60px">
<f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="quantite"></h:outputText></f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{commande.quantite}"></h:outputText>
</rich:column>


</rich:scrollableDataTable>
</h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

could you please help me to resolve the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` only work if the class is annotated with spring annotation like `@Controller`, `@Component` etc.

Either you can use

`@Component` with `@Autowired`

```
@Component("commandeBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CommandeBean implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private transient Commandser commandeser;
```

or

`@ManagedBean` with `@ManagedProperty(#{'commandeser'})` and having getter and setter for that property.

```
@ManagedBean(name="commandeBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CommandeBean implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(#{"commandeser"})
private transient Commandser commandeser;

//Getter Setter for commandeser
```